# 配列のテキスト出力を行いたいです。

Tags: php

下記の配列を.txt出力内容のように出力したいのですが、
以下の書き方ですとどうしてもarrayの文字が一緒に出力されてしまいます。
書き方やミスなどご指摘いただけると助かりますので教えていただけますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
$array[] = 'header';
$array[] = [0]'str1'
           [1]'str2'
           [2]'str3'
$array[] = 'footer';

file_put_contents ( "$url" , $array, FILE_APPEND );
```

-.txt出力内容------------
header
str1
str2
str3
footer

Comment: `$array[1]` に入る値は文字列でしょうか、文字列の配列でしょうか？

Comment: 出力に要素ごとの改行は必要でしょうか？

Comment: 書き漏れてしまっていてすみませんでした。文字列の配列が入ります。また出力の要素ごとの改行が必要になります。

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じでしょうか？
joinする改行コードを環境依存にしているので適宜変更してもらえれば…

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    'header',
    array(
        'str1',
        'str2',
        'str3',
    ),
    'footer',
);

file_put_contents ( "$url" , join(PHP_EOL, iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr)), false)), FILE_APPEND );
```

Answer (score 0):

ご質問にあるコードをそのまま実行するとシンタックス（構文）エラーが発生しています。発生している箇所は以下です。

```
$array[] = [0]'str1'
       [1]'str2'
       [2]'str3'
```

まず、PHP文の終わりにはセミコロンが必要になります。
また、配列に何かを割り当てる場合は

```
$array[0] = 'str1';
```

といった書き方になります。
この場合配列$arrayのインデックス[0]に'str1'という文字列を割り当てたということになります。
従って、先ほどのエラーが発生していた例を修正すると、

```
$array[0] = 'str1';
$array[1] = 'str2';
$array[2] = 'str3';
```

このように書き直す必要があります。
今回は、文字列を順番に追加していくだけなのでさらに簡略化することができます。

```
$array[] = "header"; //index0
$array[] = "str1";   //index1
$array[] = "str2";   //index2
$array[] = "str3";   //index3
$array[] = "footer"; //index4

file_put_contents ( '/any/dir/hoge.txt' , $array, FILE_APPEND );
```

$array[]の括弧[]は、単純に「次のインデックスに追加する」といった意味合いを持ちます。

Comment: 質問意図として、 flatten ではない配列の中身を flatten にして出力したい、ということではないかと思ったので、質問者さんにコメントで確認してみました。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。原点に戻ったつもりが間違った記述をしていました…、また言葉足らずですみません…。nekketsuuuさんのおっしゃったように  flatten ではない配列の中身を flatten にして出力したい(勉強始めたばかりなもので今flattenというものを知りました…)ということをやりたいと思っています。